# *ngFor "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined" WITH pre-definition AND *ngIf

Tags: angular

## It was a missing equals sign!

This one is a doozy. I'm getting some data via observable and processing it, then pushing it to an array that's predefined to be empty. Then I'm trying to iterate over the array in my template but it's telling me that things are undefined.

Even though I've defined the array at the start of my template (so the *ngFor shouldn't even iterate if it's empty), it's still telling me that my properties' parents are undefined. SO I stuck it under an *ngIf to only render if the array has a length, and it still complained.

Then I stuck ANOTHER *ngIf to tell if the object was defined before even starting to render and I get no error, but also no data. At all. Console.log outputs the object just fine.

I thought maybe change detection wasn't running and so it wasn't picking up the array pushes, so I made a new array with a spread operator, but that didn't help.

This is super confusing, as I'm using *ngFor and *ngIf and observables all over this app.

component:

```
    brochure: Asset[] = [];
 ....
    this.warehouse.forEach(object => {
      this.brochure.push(this.rosterQuery.assetIterate(this.manifest,object,[]))
    });
    this.brochure = [...this.brochure];
    console.log(this.brochure)
```

template:

```
  <div class="scrollable" *ngIf="brochure.length">
    <ng-container *ngFor"let object of brochure">
      <ng-container *ngIf="object">
        {{object.text}}
```

[image: Console.log plus error]

Edit: Just for funsies before bed, I tried: JSON stringify/parse to make sure it wasn't some nested reference issue; and manually detecting changes with ChangeDetectorRef. Still no luck.

Edit 2: oh, also when I'm not using the *ngIf to check the length of `brochure` (which I don't really feel I need to do considering it's reading an empty array at first), I get a whole different error that won't even let me compile: `Property 'object' does not exist on type 'AssetInventoryComponent'.`

Comment: This looks kind of strange, the inner *ngIf should prevent this error. You could try another approach by optional chaining the text property instead: `{{object?.text}}` - the question mark does a `null` and `undefined` check before accessing the property.

Comment: Yeah, the inner *ngIf does prevent the error (I pasted code from slightly different attempts, just to highlight the things I'd tried), but also prevents anything from showing up. Null chaining the object prevents the error but also doesn't show any text.

Comment: First, why do you spread your array into your already existing array `this.brochure = [...this.brochure];`? Second, as you already have a `ngFor`, you shouldn't need the innner `*ngIf`. Instead of object, try using a different name like `let item of brochure` - maybe a keyword is messing with the code

Comment: I'm spreading the array because I've had issues with merely pushing to array not triggering change detection. I know I shouldn't need the inner *ngIf (and it basically breaks and never shows anything if I use it). I've also tried using different names like asset(used extensively elsewhere) and item: `error TS2339: Property 'item' does not exist on type 'AssetInventoryComponent'.`

Comment: Maybe you can try the `json` pipe to see what really is inside your object at that point. Replace your `{{object.text}}` with `{{object | json}}` - this will display the object as a json output. I suspect something is not going right elsewhere and a different object is used somehow. Also, you can do the same for the whole array to see if you get the correct array.

Comment: @pascalpuetz ah clever, ty. The JSON pipe displays the object in its container just fine. ;o

Comment: Now that does not make this any easier... Is there a chance you can provide a minimal example of this on StackBlitz?

Comment: @pascalpuetz the project has about 45 components and a half dozen stores. It'll take me a bit of time to pare it down to something manageable. :) I'll work on it a bit tomorrow. I think there's something wacky with this particular component, as I just made a dead-simple test object to iterate over and it gave me the same error. Going to see about migrating everything to a fresh component and see if that does anything.

Comment: Looks like it. I just tried to reproduce this with a minimal example, and I don't see this error. This might be the result of somewhere else going wrong... Here what I tried out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbbdkm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It would help if I put the damn equals sign after the *ngFor. :'( Thanks for the help. I wish the error messages were a little more helpful.

Comment: If this was a typo error I would just delete the question.

Comment: Considering there was nothing googlable about this error with this particular typo, I'm inclined to leave it for posterity unless a mode feels otherwise.